# set header in repeater to visible.false

Tags: asp.net, header, repeater

using a repeater to display a list, if the list returns empty the table will be blank, so I have displayed a message 'table is empty' but i also want to set the visibility of the table header to false, is there a property for tis?

repeater.header or something?

Thanks

---

EDIT: for those who cant program in the dark

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSelectedUtilities" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
            <tr>   
                <th style="width:200px;">Utility</th>    
                <th style="width:200px;">Contacted</th>   
                <th style="width:200px;">Comment</th>    
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
                <th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyCheck" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>   
                <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>  
            </tr>
            <asp:Label id="labelTableEmpty" runat="server" Text="There are currently no items in this table." />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="labelTableEmpty" runat="server" Text="There are currently no items in this table." />
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Post your code - we are programming blind.

Comment: Thanks John, but careful with your attitude, remember, we are helping ***you***, for free, because ***you*** don't know how to do it. When you write a question consider how that question looks from our point of view. Is there near enough information to solve it? Because we know ***nothing*** about what you're trying to do and we also don't know how you've done what you've already done.

Comment: Bad attempt at humour, wasn't trying to offend. I am greatful for all the help I receive through this site, apologies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25770/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-john)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's change this up a little. We are going to make the repeater invisible overall and then add another label to markup and make it visible when necessary. Replace the repeater code with this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSelectedUtilities" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
            <tr>   
                <th style="width:200px;">Utility</th>    
                <th style="width:200px;">Contacted</th>   
                <th style="width:200px;">Comment</th>    
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
                <th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkMyCheck" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>   
                <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>  
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and then after the repeater add this (you can of course change the wording):

```
<asp:Label id="labelTableEmpty" runat="server" Text="There are currently no items in this table." />
```

and then in `OnPreRender` in the web form we're going to write some code:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (rptSelectedUtilities.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        rptSelectedUtilities.Visislbe = false;
        labelTableEmpty.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rptSelectedUtilities.Visislbe = true;
        labelTableEmpty.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'm glad I could be of assistance!